# c# DateTime, Timespan question about period of times

Tags: c#, datetime, time

What I'm basically looking to do is monitor a period of time between 2 dates,
say 01/01/2011 to 04/04/2011.

I am then looking for a way to then compare 2 new dates, where if these new dates fall
between the above ones i can say assign a boolean a value and if they dont i wont.

so if 02/02/2011 to 03/03/2011 then assign the boolean wheras if outside then no.
??

Comment: Slow down and take the time to ask your question appropriately. This is barely readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use normal compare operators with `DateTime` to do this.

For example

```
public bool Check(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1);
    DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2011,4,4);

    return ((d1 >= StartDate && d1 <= EndDate) && (d2 >= StartDate && d2 <= EndDate));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight-forward as:

```
bool isInside = (testDate >= startDate && testDate <= endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example show how to check if a date is between two dates.

Code has been tested and works:

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2011, 02, 02);
DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(2011, 03, 03);

if (DateTime.Now >= dtStart && DateTime.Now <= dtEnd)
{
    // Date is within range
}
```